# How to fire ng-messages on blur?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ionic-framework, ng-messages

**THE SITUATION:**

I have many forms in my angular app and i need an effective error messages system. I find [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) useful.

But i would like that the error messages appears only when the user blur out of a field, in order to be less 'aggressive'.

**ATTEMPT:**

Attempt using debouncing at 1000ms

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label"> Email alternative </span>
    <input type="email" name="email_alternative" ng-model="profile_edited.email2" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }">
</label>

<!-- Error messages for ALTERNATIVE EMAIL  -->
<label class="item item-input" ng-show="profile_edit_form.email_alternative.$error.email">
    <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="profile_edit_form.email_alternative.$error" role="alert" ng-if='profile_edit_form.email_alternative.$dirty'>
        <div class="form-error" ng-message="email">Your email address is invalid</div>
    </div>
</label>
```

In this way it will properly appears the error message if the user is not typing anything for one second.
Is the closest i get to what i want.

But sometimes for some users it may take a bit more than 1 second to type the character @. The error message may then suddenly appear and confuse the user.

But if i set the debouncing time 2 or 3 seconds is way too much. It may appear when the user is already writing in another field.

I need that the error messages fire ONLY AFTER the user blur out of the field.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i fire ngMessages on blur?

Comment: Use `$touched` instead of `$dirty`

Comment: Thank you @devqon! I have tested it out and it works exactly as i wanted! Even if is short you can write it as a reply and will accept it, since it may be useful for other users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$dirty` will evaluate to true if the text is changed in the input box. To check for the blur you can use the `$touched` property of the input field.

Checkout the forms documentation to see all form (input) properties: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$dirty` and `ng-show` to display messages when input is dirty.

```
<input type="text" name="modelName" ng-model="modelName" required />
<div ng-messages="myForm.modelName.$error" ng-show="myForm.modelName.$dirty">
    <div ng-message="required">Please Fill this model.</div>
</div>
```